# Playstore application is not showing in Oreo Version and some devices

Tags: android

I launched first application in playstore, it's not showing in some devices. I have given compatible screens in manifest. I have doubt because of that it's not showing or not. Please help me.

I launched second application, but I didn't give compatible screens in manifest, it's showing in Oreo mobile but Android less than Marshmallow devices it's not showing directly, if I give pacakge name means its showing.

This is manifest for first app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.getspot.getspot">

    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- for all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <!-- for all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <!-- for all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/getspot_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is second app manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.orange.mac.orangeplus" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="OranglePlus"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity
            android:name="com.orange.mac.orangeplus.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:label="Orange"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.orange.mac.orangeplus.Splachscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle file**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}




android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.orange.mac.orangeplus"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note: I have given target version 26, minimum version 15 but even though why first application is not showing? Please help me to fix my issues.

Comment: In the google play console, there's a list of devices that the app will be available to. Did you find your devices in that list?

Comment: Yes the devices are supported only its showing

Comment: "only its showing" - What do you mean by that? Please post a list of the devices which you expect the app to be available for and list the devices on which you can't find the app in the Play Store.